# MySQL: атрибуты столбца

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Объясните, пожалуйста, что предполагают атрибуты столбца при создании таблицы? `BINARY`, `UNSIGNED`, `UNSIGNED_ZEROFILL` и `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Первое. второе и четвёртое - просто переведите на русский.  Третье - не существует.

Comment: @Akina, то есть, в случае типа `int` это будет `unsigned int`? А в случае `text`?

Comment: *то есть, в случае типа int это будет unsigned int?* Без явного указания - тип знаковый. *А в случае text?* UNSIGNED применим только к числовым типам.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо! Тогда что даст `BINARY`? В случае числового типа и текста.

Comment: `BINARY` - это тип такой. Хранит бинарные данные. Так что неприменим к числовым данным (хотя никто не запрещает хранить бинарное представление числовых данных), а в случае хранения бинарного представления текстовых данных к ним не применяются charset/collation.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо ещё раз.